# Is the implementation of xorg opengl?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, opengl

Is the implementation of xorg opengl? As far as I know,Xorg is a implementation that for X11,Does it use opengl?

Answer (score 5):

No, Xorg itself *is not* OpenGL. However, it connects to the Direct Rendering Infrastructure (DRI for short) that can be used to *provide support for* OpenGL.

[The Mesa project](https://docs.mesa3d.org/) implements an open-source version of OpenGL - [either software-rendered or hardware-accelerated](https://docs.mesa3d.org/systems.html), depending on whether the GPU model is supported and accessible using DRI.

A third-party Xorg driver (like Nvidia's) can provide an alternative OpenGL implementation, if the author of the driver wants to do that.

So:

- the GPU hardware may provide a set of *acceleration features* that are designed for OpenGL
- a kernel DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) driver *provides DRI access* to hardware acceleration features
- Mesa (or an alternative OpenGL implementation) *implements* OpenGL either using DRI and the GPU's hardware acceleration features, or through software rendering if hardware does not support OpenGL acceleration, or if hardware access is not available
- Xorg *allows the use* of OpenGL through the GLX extension of the X11 protocol. Any GLX requests will be essentially passed through to Mesa (or to an alternative OpenGL implementation, if applicable)
- an application (including a desktop environment like GNOME or KDE) can *use* OpenGL
  either using DRI (bypassing Xorg entirely) or through the X11 GLX extension.

This diagram [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX) may be helpful. In the diagram, Mesa (or an alternative OpenGL implementation) is the *OpenGL DRI driver*:

[image: Linux graphics drivers and DRI]

Comment: thanks for your help